# How to get an if statement working with variable inside

Tags: jquery, if-statement

This is my code but I cannot get the if statement to stop running based on the condition. It's like the function thinks the variable is always 0 even though i'm adding one every time.

```
var this_current_position = 0;
var numItems = 8;

if (this_current_position <= 4 ) {
    $(".fa-arrow-right").click(function(){
            $('.mobile-gallery-content').animate({"left": '+=-324'});
            this_current_position += 1;
    });
};
```

Can anyone find any mistakes in my code?

Comment: you should try this with a `while` instead of `if`, also does the `this_current_position` increment? and it should be inside the click function as @Liam specified

Comment: this `if` needs to be inside the click function. That said you should avoid using global variables like this.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Did you try to print the variable each time?

Comment: the update current position is only triggered if the position <= 4 *and* the arrow-right is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement will only run the first time through the code. At that time `this_current_position` is always `0` and the click handler will be registered. Each time the click handler is invoked `this_current_position` will be incremented, but there's no logic in the handler to check this value.

Perhaps you meant to put the check inside the handler:

```
var this_current_position = 0;
var numItems = 8;

$(".fa-arrow-right").click(function(){
    if (this_current_position <= 4 ) {
        $('.mobile-gallery-content').animate({"left": '+=-324'});
        this_current_position += 1;
    }
});
```